# The recv command does not work as it should when threading and the server crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I set up a TCP server with the Python socket library that multiple devices can be connected to. Since I use threading here, I regularly accept new incoming connections and try to recruit messages in the list. My question is that usually recv threading gets stuck somewhere. Sometimes the server, which is running smoothly, sometimes hangs on the first day. Showing Incoming Connections but not receiving messages. c in clients, so when I print each threaded connection before get in recv command

```
Now on <socket.socket fd=8, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.31.15.96', 9680), raddr=('24.133.144.150', 56446)>
Now on <socket.socket fd=8, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.31.15.96', 9680), raddr=('24.133.144.150', 56446)>
Now on <socket.socket fd=8, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.31.15.96', 9680), raddr=('24.133.144.150', 56446)>
Now on <socket.socket fd=8, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.31.15.96', 9680), raddr=('24.133.144.150', 56446)>
Now on <socket.socket fd=8, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.31.15.96', 9680), raddr=('24.133.144.150', 56446)>
Now on <socket.socket fd=8, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.31.15.96', 9680), raddr=('24.133.144.150', 56446)>
Now on <socket.socket fd=8, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.31.15.96', 9680), raddr=('24.133.144.150', 56446)>
Now on <socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.31.15.96', 9680), raddr=('24.133.144.150', 56456)>
```

In the loop, it continued to show the same port (probably more than thousand times) until it sent a new message from the phone.
I am showing the problematic part because the code I wrote is about 500 lines after recv.

```
import socket
import threading

host = '172.31.15.96'
port = 9680   

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("socket created")
    s.bind((host, port))
    print("socket connected {} port".format(port))
    s.listen(250)
    print("socket listening")
    db.logHere.insert_one({"socket log": {"socket created and port opened": port, "Time": time()}})

except socket.error as msg:
    print("Error:", msg)
    db.logHere.insert_one(
        {"Socket Log": {"Error happened": msg, "Time": time()}})

clients = [] # this is list for connected client

def accept():
    while True:
        global clients
        client, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connection from:', addr)
        db.logHere.insert_one({"Connection Log": {"Connection ip from": str(addr[0])+":"+str(addr[1]), "Connection time": time()}, "Time": time()})
        clients.append(client)

def new_message():
    while True:
        for c in clients:
            print("Now on", c) # I just try to use this print if new message thread work or stopped
            try:
                message = c.recv(2048)
                if message:
                    #there is my split or sendall commands. I put if messages inside try advice from : Marquis of Lorne*
            except socket.error as err:
                print("socket error", err)
                c.close()

threading.Thread(target=accept).start()
threading.Thread(target=new_message).start()
```

What should I do in order to solve this problem and to be able to operate properly with every incoming connection, that is, to maintain a healthy server?
I think my main problem is i cannot delete disconnected client frim that clients list. try except is not enough for that. How can i understand one of client disconnected?

**I apologize for my incomplete and incorrect language usage. My native language is not English.

Comment: The code that processes `message` shoudl not execute if there was an exception. Move it.

Comment: But there is no any message received. Thats why it is need to be pass? Am I wrong? With your word, if message need to be inside of try right?

Comment: You should never loop over connected sockets without first using `select` to make sure that there is something to read. Failing to do so is a risk of hanging in the loop if no data is present. And a 0 length read is the indication that the peer has closed the connection, so you should test that and remove the client when it happens.

Comment: If you had given a [mcve], I could have posted an anwser with some code...

Comment: If I just do, ```if len(message)==0: clients.remove(c)``` is this the solution?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I try to do minimal reproducible example, I hope it was OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal fix to your code using `select` to only read on client sockets having available data and removing closed sockets from the list:

```
...
def new_message():
    while True:
        # don't try to wait on a empty list...
        if len(clients) == 0:
            sleep(5)
        else:
            ready, _, _ = select.select(clients, [], [])
            # only loop on sockets having available data to read
            for c in ready:
                print("Now on", c) # I just try to use this print if new message thread work or stopped
                try:
                    message = c.recv(2048)
                    if message:
                        #there is my split or sendall commands. I put if messages inside try advice from : Marquis of Lorne*
                        print(message.decode())
                    else:
                        clients.remove(c)
                except socket.error as err:
                    ...
```

But in fact, you could include the listening socket on the select list, and fully discard one thread:

```
...
clients = [s] # this is list for connected client AND the listening socket

##def accept():
##    while True:
##        global clients
##        client, addr = s.accept()
##        print('Connection from:', addr)
##        db.logHere.insert_one({"Connection Log": {"Connection ip from": str(addr[0])+":"+str(addr[1]), "Connection time": time()}, "Time": time()})
##        clients.append(client)

def new_message():
    while True:
        ready, _, _ = select.select(clients, [], [])
        for c in ready:                    # loop over ready sockets
            if c == s:                     # special processing for listening one
                try:
                    client, addr = s.accept()
                except socket.error:       # exit if the listening socket is closed
                    for x in clients:
                        x.close()
                    return 
                print('Connection from:', addr)
                db.logHere.insert_one({"Connection Log": {"Connection ip from": str(addr[0])+":"+str(addr[1]), "Connection time": time()}, "Time": time()})
                clients.append(client)
            else:
                print("Now on", c) # I just try to use this print if new message thread work or stopped
                try:
                    message = c.recv(2048)
                    if message:
                        #there is my split or sendall commands. I put if messages inside try advice from : Marquis of Lorne*
                        print(message.decode())
                    else:
                        clients.remove(c)
                except socket.error as err:
                    print("socket error", err)
                    c.close()

##threading.Thread(target=accept).start()
threading.Thread(target=new_message).start()
```

Comment: if i discard one thread, there wont be any client in clients list. Thats why probably this code doesnt work bcs there is no any ready client.

Comment: @MertiCan Have you seen that in my modified unique thread code, `clients` is initialized with the listening socket?

Comment: Bu there is no any pre known socket. I make all of this socket inside of accept block. I apologize if my opinion is wrong. Sometimes threads stop running back, when I write a backend application what can I do to switch to it? Is there any possibility of a crash because of other tasks on another screen with Tmux? I got a connection timeout error a couple of times while handling with this problem, it gave the error socket.error is not subscriptionable and I just started to print the exception on the screen.